# UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource doesn't animate properly on apply

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I have a list of items, they are displayed in decreasing order by amount in a list. I hash them by name, so when I change the amounts, they should reorder smoothly on apply.
When I call the `apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)` function on `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, it doesn't reorder the cells with a smooth animation, but flashes instead and everything is in place with no "reordering".

```
struct Item: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let amount: Int

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}

// when user taps, I call this
dataSource.apply(makeSnapshot())
```

Comment: What is the type of your `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SectionType, ItemType>`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` not only uses the hash to tell which item is which, but the `==` operator too.
This solved the problem:

```
struct Item: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let amount: Int

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Category, rhs: Category) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, was this detail about == referenced in documentation at the time?